# Setting the currentTime() in Video.js doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to implement video player that remembers where user has left watching video, using video.js player. Player is saving current video time into local storage, and when user returns to the video, it sets that time, so users could continue where they left.
And sometimes player method `currentTime(time)` doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```js
function _(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

const player = videojs("video-id")
let videoId = undefined

function playVideo() {
    const textElement = _("text-id")
    videoId = textElement.value
    if (!player.paused) {
        player.pause()
    }
    player.reset()
    player.src({type: 'video/mp4', src: `/download/${videoId}`})
    player.load()
    const leftTime = localStorage.getItem(videoId)
    console.log("Before set:", player.currentTime()) // 0 (int)
    console.log("Left time:", leftTime) // 173 (string)
    if (leftTime !== null) {
        const leftTimeInt = parseInt(leftTime)
        console.log("Left time int: ", leftTimeInt) // 173 (int)
        player.currentTime(leftTimeInt)
        console.log("After set:", player.currentTime()) // 0 (int)
    }
    console.log("New video time: ", player.currentTime()) // 0 (int)
}
```

I expect it to log "After set: 173", but it doesn't happen.
And Video.js documentation only says that currentTime() allows to "Get or set the current time (in seconds)".

Comment: why did you opt to save it on local storage? why not a database so that your users can resume watching from any device?

Comment: @seriously I don't have control over backend side, so this is the only option. And there is no user accounts, so there is nothing to bind with "resume time".

Comment: perhaps you need to use `.ready` - also, the seek time doesn't need to be an integer. Not your issue, but good to know - in fact it can be a string (as long as the string represents number - note, I'm saying number, not integer)